# Why do the Shuttle's external tanks appear to be rusted?

Tags: launch, rockets, nasa, space-shuttle, engineering

Wikipedia article states as

> STS-1 at liftoff. The
>   External Tank was painted
>   white for the first two
>   Space Shuttle launches.
>   From STS-3 on, it was
>   left unpainted.

[image: source Wikipedia]
 [image: source:Wikipedia]

I wonder why the early shuttles External tanks are not painted and after NASA  started painting the ET's why it painted it in color of rusted iron why not other color's ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From STS-3, the tank was left unpainted, the brown color is the natural color of the insulation foam, [see this PDF](http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/114022main_TPS_FS.pdf). The color would get darker from exposure to the sun.
The tanks of STS-1 and 2 were painted white, but this took several hundred kg of paint, and after STS-1 and 2 [tests showed](http://www.space.com/2282-columbias-white-external-fuel-tanks.html) that the paint wasn't necessary.

Comment: The more interesting question was whether the paint would have helped protect from falling ice or foam chunks. I doubt it but this made me wonder.

Comment: From the linked article: 'The paint also did not prevent foam from popping free of Columbia's fuel tank during its first two launches'