# Did the Saturn V rocket have any purely aesthetic features that didn't serve an actual function?

Tags: rockets, nasa, apollo-program, saturn-v

The rocket itself is magnificent, yes, but with so many ins and outs to it, curious if the entire design was solely purpose built, or if there were features specifically for aesthetic purposes.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73138/discussion-on-question-by-hwp08-did-the-saturn-v-rocket-have-any-purely-aestheti).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I don't know of any features on the Saturn V that are solely aesthetic in purpose. The flags and USA markings come closest, but they are ostensibly there to identify the origin of the vehicle. The overall white paint scheme is to minimize heating of the cryogenic propellant tanks from sunlight. [The interrupted black stripes along the fuselage provide visual/photographic reference points,](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-black-and-white-patterns-on-some-rockets?rq=1) particularly helpful in seeing if the vehicle is changing its roll attitude and determining exact rates of motion in frame-by-frame photo analysis.

The overall long and skinny cylindrical shape, and all of the large-scale features, are functions of aerodynamics and manufacturability as well as the functions of each part. The proportions are not necessarily optimal for either of those major constraints, and some engineer's aesthetic sense (or Wernher von Braun's) may have influenced them, but engineering requirements certainly dominate the silhouette.

The conical fairings at the base of the first stage are needed to streamline the outboard engines, which are mounted at the edge of the stage; their shape was probably chosen for ease of manufacture rather than for aesthetics or optimal aerodynamics.

It's occasionally claimed that the fins on the first stage have no function and are a purely aesthetic choice on von Braun's part, but this is incorrect. The fins are fixed in place; attitude control during the first-stage burn is performed by the gimbaled first-stage engines. The fins help keep the stage from tumbling during the first-to-second-stage separation, and [in some catastrophic multiple-engine-failure situations, would keep the rocket stable long enough for the launch escape system to get the command module away](https://books.google.com/books?id=MiYDAAAAMBAJ&lpg=PA185&ots=Cw7tIvaYUk&dq=Since%20the%20flight%20path--usually%20into%20orbit--is%20predetermined%2C%20and%20thus%20%20ideally%20suited%20to%20programed%20changes%20in%20ga%20in%20setting%2C%20it%20might%20appear%20that%20there%20should%20be%20no%20need%20for%20fins.&pg=PA185#v=onepage&q&f=false). They probably would have been deleted to save weight if more Saturn Vs had been ordered.

A non-tapering or slowly-tapering shape is good for aerodynamics, [especially at transonic and supersonic speeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_rule); some drag is induced at each change in diameter, so you don't want to do it abruptly or without good reason. The five engines of the Saturn V second stage forced its diameter to be similar to that of the first stage, so it was convenient to make it identical.

The third stage, S-IVB, was also used as the second stage for the smaller Saturn I-B launcher, and its diameter matched that of the Saturn I-B first stage, avoiding a taper there.

The tapered adapter section between the third stage and the Apollo CSM is just large enough to contain the LM and the very large engine bell of the CSM; the conical shape of the command module is established by its method of re-entry, and so on.

I'm sure some of the Saturns carried some kind of graffiti or assembly workers' signatures somewhere in the interior of the assembly, which you could call a form of art, but those aren't designed features.

Comment: I always wondered about the fins.

Comment: @OrganicMarble The function of the fins was apparently to keep pitch/yaw within the operational limits of the escape system even if there was a worst-case failure of the engines (severe thrust asymmetry, engine "hard-over", etc.).

Comment: Great info! They always seemed too small to do much.

Comment: The black-and-white paint was claimed to be a bit of an affectation inspired by the "checkerboard" patterns on WWII V2s, but this article explains their value: https://www.popsci.com/why-was-saturn-v-black-and-white

Comment: Ah, yeah, I'll add a mention of that.

Comment: @AnthonyX and served the same purpose on prototype/test articles of the A4/V2 series. Production V2s were painted in a variety of camouflage schemes to make detection during transport and storage more difficult.

Comment: @RussellBorogrove excellent answer, you may wish to check into "nontapering or slowly tapering shape is good at transonic or supersonic".  Indeed the Saturn V had sharp breaks from top to bottom.  So do "diamond airfoils" for supersonic wings.  These function to keep turbulence *away* from the rocket as it goes supersonic.   The V-2 had smooth contours (and no area ruling).  Many inexplicably broke apart until the fuselage was strengthened.  But your bit about the fins is certainly correct.

Comment: Reference for the utility of the fins from von Braun:https://books.google.com/books?id=MiYDAAAAMBAJ&lpg=PA185&ots=Cw7tIvaYUk&dq=Since%20the%20flight%20path--usually%20into%20orbit--is%20predetermined%2C%20and%20thus%20%20ideally%20suited%20to%20programed%20changes%20in%20ga%20in%20setting%2C%20it%20might%20appear%20that%20there%20should%20be%20no%20need%20for%20fins.&pg=PA185#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @OrganicMarble Great find.

Answer (score 8):

The Apollo program had some difficulty keeping the weight of the stack within limits. That makes it unlikely significant weight was spent on aesthetics.

Comment: Some paint weighing less than a 1/10,000 of the lift off weight of Saturn V should not be a problem if applied to the first stage only.

Comment: When you're counting grams up top to get the mission parameters right, you have to be counting tens of kilograms down at the bottom to also keep things straight - and that certainly covers any paint visible on the outside of the vehicle, or most decorative details you could add to something that large.

Comment: @Uwe, you know why the Space Shuttle's external tank was red?  Because not painting it let them reduce the weight at liftoff by 0.013%.

Comment: @Uwe I don't know about the reasoning in design choices of the Saturn V. I just keep thinking about how heavy two five gallon buckets of normal paint are, and remembering that episode of _Malcolm_ _in_ _the_ _Middle_ where the paint gets so thick it falls on the dad.

Comment: @Mark I'm not sure whether it's accurate, but I recall reading somewhere that the Space Shuttle external fuel tanks initially *were* white, but a kid asked a NASA public relations person how much the paint weighed, or some similar question, and the PR person had to ask an engineer, and after the idea bounced around a bit they decided to leave the paint off subsequent missions.

Comment: @Steve, the first two launches had the tanks painted white to protect the insulation from UV damage while the Shuttle was sitting on the launch pad.  Turns out UV damage wasn't a problem, so the paint was omitted from future tanks.

Comment: On this [page](https://bernd-leitenberger.de/saturn-geschichte.shtml) there is a table comparing all Saturn V missions from 8 to 17 in payload (Nutzlast) and the stages dry (leer) and tanked (betankt). When the first stage of Apollo 8 was separated, 34,000 kg were left in the tanks. That does not look like counting grams.

Comment: Apollo 8 wasn't the worst-case scenario.

Comment: @Uwe 34,000 kg out of about 2,000,000 kg is less than 2% margin, and running out early isn't a great idea. You count grams *where safely possible*. If skipping some paint allows for some extra fuel, that's a pretty reasonable trade.

Comment: Apollo 8 saved 15 tons by leaving the LM at home.

Comment: @Mark: Most of the reason was that the paint was even more prone to falling off during launch than the foam itself was, which created serious FOD concerns.